# Is there a nose generator equivalent in junit?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, nose

I mostly write Selenium WebDriver tests in Java but I recently had to work on some Selenium tests written in Python using nose. I noticed a great nose tool that generates separate test cases while iterating over a set of values (e.g. for testing every item in a drop-down list and getting a result entry for each).

http://swordstyle.com/func_test_tutorial/part_one/extra_generative_tests.html

Is there something similar that I could use in junit?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, take a look at the [JUNIT Data Provider library](https://github.com/TNG/junit-dataprovider)

From the docs:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.tngtech.java.junit.dataprovider.DataProvider;
import com.tngtech.java.junit.dataprovider.DataProviderRunner;
import com.tngtech.java.junit.dataprovider.UseDataProvider;

@RunWith(DataProviderRunner.class)
public class DataProviderTest {

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] dataProviderAdd() {
        // @formatter:off
        return new Object[][] {
                { 0, 0, 0 },
                { 1, 1, 2 },
                /* ... */
        };
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Test
    @UseDataProvider("dataProviderAdd")
    public void testAdd(int a, int b, int expected) {
        // Given:

        // When:
        int result = a + b;

        // Then:
        assertEquals(expected, result);
    }
}
```